# Getting error while executing find Odd Even Number

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```java
package BasicPrograms;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEvenNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int no;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number :");
        no = s.nextInt();
        
        if(no%2==0)
        {System.out.println("Even Number");}
        else
        {System.out.println("Odd Number");}
    }

}
```

This is the error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\ARVIND\Downloads\poi-bin-5.1.0-20211024\poi-bin-5.1.0\auxiliary\batik-script-1.14.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.batik.bridge.RhinoInterpreterFactory not in module

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1260

Comment: Its a bug? Then what else can be done.

Comment: Create a new project, and look out for any module-settings you use. Then copy everything you have over from the old to the new.

Comment: Looks like you have a module-info.java in the project making it modular. Deleting the module-info.java will revert to the non-modular style.

Comment: I have already deleted module-info.java file from the project. But still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Path giving you the exception, please provide the valid path, or convert your project to maven

> C:\Users\ARVIND\Downloads\